# Getting posts link in WordPress

Tags: loop, permalinks

This is a snippet code to get user's location.

How do we get the link to the post in $temp[0] = $post_x->post_title; ?

(I get the relevant link on it)

```
<?php
            global $seller_details;
            $loc_arr = array();
            while(have_posts()) : the_post(); global $post,$product;
                $loc_arr[get_the_ID()] = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'my_location', true);
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_query();

            $locations = array();
            $i = 1;
            foreach( $loc_arr as $key => $str ){
                $temp = array();
                $ex = explode(',', $str);
                $post_x = get_post($key);
                $temp[0] = $post_x->post_title;
                $temp[1] = $ex[0];
                $temp[2] = $ex[1];
                $temp[3] = $i;

                $locations[] = $temp;

                $i ++;
            }

            $locations = json_encode($locations);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get_permalink( $post_x )` to get the post‘s URL.

Documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/

Comment: Thanks . 
I want to have title and link together